Formal grammar for Standard ABAP?
Has there ever been a published document containing the formal grammar of Standard ABAP, for example in EBNF?
I could not find any up-to-date information, but maybe someone knows of previous documents?

I don‘t think that such a thing exists, and writing one nowadays is pretty hard given the 40 years of backwards compability …

There's no official grammar expressed formally. The only official documentation is here but you'll have to read the whole book and collect the grammar manually (good luck!)
But you can find the most advanced and up-to-date work about the ABAP language versions here (I don't really know where exactly, I let you search):

https://abaplint.org

NB: I guess that "Standard ABAP" refers to the unrestricted ABAP language version, as opposed to the restricted ABAP language versions.

abaplint seems to be a four year old handwritten RND parser, so I doubt it is useful for extracting a grammar …
